# can't find the solution

Tags: java

```
public class BinaryToDecimal{
public static void main(String[]args){
    int binary = 101011101;
    int d = 10;
    int l = 1;
    for (int j=1;j<=8;j++){
        int r = (binary/d%10)*l;
        int k = r;
        int z = r + k;
        d*=10;
        l*=2;
    }
    System.out.println("The binary number " + binary + " is equivalent to "+ z +" in decimal."); // z here is out of scope of for
}
```

}

I need to finish this assignment using only the for loop, but I can't find a working code... This is the best i did.

Comment: oops.. i can only use for loops... what should i do ?

Comment: You should declare the `z` variable outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Only use loops for what? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: I realise you're just learning.  That's why NOW would be the perfect time to get OUT of the habit of using single-letter variable names.  Please use names that actually express what the variable is being used for.

Comment: i think Titus has the answer but where exactly should i declare it ?

Comment: the out come should be the binary number in decimal

Comment: Yes, Titus has the right answer.  Write `int z = 0;` before the `for` loop.  Or change the name of it to something better.  Then remove `int` from the line `z = r + k;`.  If you don't do that, then you're creating a new `z` each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class BinaryToDecimal{
public static void main(String[]args){
    int binary = 101011101;
    int powerOfTen = 10;
    int powerOfTwo = 1;
    int Decimal = 0;
    for (int j=1;j<=8;j++){
        int splitAnswer = (binary/powerOfTen%10)*powerOfTwo;
        int old = splitAnswer;
        Decimal = splitAnswer + old;
        powerOfTen*=10;
        powerOfTwo*=2;
    }
    System.out.println("The binary number " + binary + " is equivalent to "+ Decimal +" in decimal.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple algorithm using the `2^x` logic.

What it is basically doing is :

If we encounter `1` in the binary variable, we add `2^(Position of the 1)` to the `decimal` variable

```
class MyClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bin = 101;
        String binary = String.valueOf(bin);
        int decimal = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < binary.length() ; i++){
            if (binary.charAt(i) == '1'){
                decimal += Math.pow(2, binary.length() - i - 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(decimal);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is beyond my level. but thanks i did get my answer.

Comment: @AdelHabbal No problem, Have a nice evening btw :)